# Installing GFortran on Mavericks

Tags: scipy, osx-mavericks, gfortran

I  have succeeded with installing numpy and now I am trying to install scipy on Mavericks. The requirement is GFortran but when I am trying to install it, I get a message:
"Unapproved caller.
SecurityAgent may only be invoked by Apple software."

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the computer has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this by using the `installer` command instead of the gui

```
 ## SETUP
  # get pacakge
wget http://coudert.name/software/gfortran-4.9.0-Mavericks.dmg
  # mount
hdiutil attach gfortran-4.9.0-Mavericks.dmg
  # issue with clicking desktop icon then pkg icon
  # "Unapproved caller. SecurityAgent may only be invoked by Apple software"
## INSTALL    
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/gfortran-4.9.0-Mavericks/gfortran.pkg -target /

## test install
which gfortran
/usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

Another solution might be to use the brew/fink/macports package. I'm using this package instead of e.g. `brew install gcc` because (when R is compiling fortran code), I'm getting:

> FATAL:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!